# Creating a URL for Federated Users to Access the AWS Management Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I have created a script to generate a URL that Enables Federated Users to Access the AWS Management Console with limited access, The script is written in python using following below AWS documentation -

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html#STSConsoleLink_programPython)

The script is generating link perfectly fine, I have given SessionDuration= 7200 seconds which is 2 Hours in the script.
But Most of the time the problem I am facing is the URL getting expired before completing 2 Hours of time like in 5 minutes, 10 minutes.
The URL is encrypted with the session token So I can't able to check its end time, The server time 
is set in UTC which enables the link works global across the wold.

So If someone using the same thing and getting the same issue or having any solution for this problem please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code that you have written to generate these URLs? We can’t figure out where the problem is if we can’t see the code.

Comment: Hi Joey, You can find the code in the above-shared AWS documentation under Example Code Using Python. I Have used the same code and the link is created with that and working fine. The only problem is it's expiring before end time. Here is my code https://github.com/rahulgaikwadsipl/aws-python-aws-federated-user/blob/master/link.py